# Error with Python modulo on scientific notation

Tags: python, modulo

I hope someone can help me with an explanation for this strange result on large divisor, or suggest me with some keywords so can I get a better search.

```
>>> m = 1e9+9
>>> n = 1000000009
>>> m == n
True
>>> 2549015908609065 % m
885667930.0
>>> 2549015908609065 % n
885667930
>>> 2549015908609065L % n
885667930L
>>> 2549015908609065L % m
885667930.0

>>> 254901590860906524041412370460835L % m
98506080.0
>>> 254901590860906524041412370460835L % n
327998297L

>>> 254901590860906524041412370460835L % int(m)
327998297L
```

Comment: Floating point precision over larger numbers is diminished. See `sys.float_info()` for the precise precision offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m = 1e9+9` stores the number as a float; however `n = 1000000009` stores the numbers as an integer.

When you divide an integer number by a float, python implicitly outputs a float as a result; However, when you divide an integer by another integer, you get the integral quotient.
The precision of Float over bigger numbers gets reduced.

If you notice,

```
>>> 254901590860906524041412370460835L % m
98506080.0
#outputted a float with different precision

>>> 254901590860906524041412370460835L % n
327998297L
#outputted a long int
```

Check http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_numbers.htm for a basic tutorial on python numbers

Comment: "the way numbers are interpreted in python" might lead to wrong conclusions. That's the way floats (IEEE 754) are interpreted by every programming language.

Comment: Thank you everyone for pointing out the precision on float number. I was assuming 2549015908609065L is sufficiently large to see an error if there is any. Good lesson learned on this error. Thank again!

Comment: @bizi, ansh0l The long-int output is also not exact here. How is that the right solution?

Comment: @Dhara I thought the OP meant to ask **why** this was happening (the reason for which is float vs integer representation of 1e9 + 9), and not how to rectify it, so I answered it accordingly

Comment: @ansh0l I think what confused me, was that you seem to have pasted the wrong result (at least for int, I didnt check for float). The modulo operation should have given you the last 9 digits of the number

Comment: @Dhara, the main concern in my question is the difference when my divisor is (very) large. It will cause the result to be totally different. I am sorry if my test cases confuse you that the long/int format of the output is the objective of the question. I appreciate your answer and your link.

Comment: Besides, I choose ansh0| answer mostly base on the way of wording.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are seeing strange results is because you are performing modulo on floating point numbers, which have an inexact representation. The documentation on the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module highlights this quite well.

To perform exact operations on very large number, you can use the decimal class as follows:

```
from decimal import *
print Decimal(2549015908609065) % Decimal(1e9) # Gives the answer you expect
```

Comment: It's exceedingly unusual to need anything other than integers for modular arithmetic. (A real mathematician would probably look at you funny if you said you wanted to use mod on anything else.) So you might as well just use `int` rather than `Decimal`.

Comment: @JohnY A real mathematician may not like it, but the modulo operation on floating point numbers has a precise defintion "Computes the remainder of the division operation x/y, that is, the value x-ny for some integer n such that the magnitude of the result is less than the magnitude of y." and it is not that unusual to use it. For example: given a point moving on a circle and the distance it has moved, a modulo by 2*pi will give you the location of the point on the circle

Comment: The special case of radial arithmetic is always mod **exactly** 2*pi (so not arbitrary real numbers). Neither `float` nor `Decimal` can accurately represent pi, so trying to calculate it in this manner is going to be inexact. If you're doing an engineering problem that doesn't require exact math, then `float` will already be good enough. So `Decimal` doesn't buy you anything in either case. If you're doing number theory, you need `int`; if you're doing engineering, `float` will be accurate enough; and both `int` and `float` are faster than `Decimal`.